# Displaying a selectable list in Onepage Checkout and adding the selected item to an order

Tags: orders, onepage-checkout, customer-account, edit-order, billing-address

All,

This question is an extension to my previous post: 
[I need to override an Account email address with a Billing email address when Placing the Order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44222/i-need-to-override-an-account-email-address-with-a-billing-email-address-when-pl)

which I could not get working, or figure out what I was doing wrong.

However, in thinking more about what we are trying to achieve, we don't need to log in with an account at all, we can simply use Guest checkout as per the SCENARIO below. This means that the system will be simpler to administer (we are confident that the retailers will regularly mislay their account login/password details).

So, to achieve this we need to cater for the following customisation:

1)  Keeping the Retailers details (customer id, business/contact name and Address) in the system, as a simple CSV or XML config file (or possibly as a new DB table)?

2)  Having a selectable Dropdown of authorised retailers retrieved from the above configuration file at the first stage of Checkout, i.e. instead of Checkout Method

In terms of 1) I did think about using a standard Customer Account record, but this means I will also need to override the Account email address with the Billing email address for payment gateway purposes.

As iterated in my original post (referred to above), I am **not** a seasoned Magento pro; while I have PHP/HTML/XML and some Script knowledge, I don't have deep Magento configuration knowledge.

If anyone has done anything similar, or can guide me to an article that does something similar, or provides the simplest/method to achieve this, I would be grateful as I have been working on this on and off for a week already.

**SCENARIO**

We are selling a range of golf products via our Store which can only be exclusively ordered and purchased from our store through a number of authorised retailers.

Also, the product(s) can **ONLY** be delivered to the authorised retailer's address, i.e. the customer cannot request the product(s) to be delivered to their home address. We will therefore need to store each retailer's unique details in the system. This will contain a single Shipping Address that will be used when the applicable retailer is selected at the Checkout stage.

The customer can either select the product(s) and create the order while in store with the retailer, or remotely from his/her own computer/device (if they decide not to buy at the time).

The buying process will be thus:

1. Products are selected and added to Cart
2. Customer proceeds to Checkout (no login or registration required)
3. An authorised Retailer is selected (via a dropdown box)
4. Customer completes Billing Address (with a valid customer email address)
5. The selected Retailer's Shipping Address is posted as display only (for visual confirmation)
6. Payment Method is selected
7. Order is Reviewed and the customer pays via Worldpay/Paypal
8. Customer receives the transaction confirmation email from the payment gateway and the order confirmation from the Magento store

The Order will need to be passed with the Billing Form Customer Email address (as in 4 above) and the Shipping Address passed will need to be the selected Retailer in 3, as displayed in 5.